# Как проверить письмо на почте?

Tags: python

Мне надо, что бы программа находящейся на другом компьютере проверяла письма на моей почте. Если это команда, то выполняла её. Но не могу понять как проверять письма на почте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сперва я хочу вас предупредить о том, что ваш подход выглядит несколько небезопасным: ваш почтовый ящик будет получать письма от кого угодно. Если всё-таки решитесь на этот эксперимент, добавьте хотя бы фильтрацию по адресу источника письма, чтобы команда выполнялась только при поступлении с управляемого вами почтового адреса.

Для чтения почтового содержимого почтового ящика вы можете использовать протоколы **POP3** и **IMAP**. Вам следует знать, поддерживает ли ваш почтовый сервис для принимающего почту ящика работу по выбранному протоколу, и убедиться в том, что он включен в настройках вашей учетной записи. Я приведу небольшой пример для использования IMAP для Gmail. Более подробную информацию вы можете найти здесь: https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.utils import parseaddr

imap_session = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
imap_session.login("your@email.adr", "YouRpAssworD") # авторизация
imap_session.select('INBOX')                         # выбор "Входящих" сообщений
typ, data = imap_session.search(None, 'ALL')

if len(data[0]) > 0: 
    for num in data[0].split():
        typ, data = imap_session.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        mail_ = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1]) # здесь ваше письмо, вам остается лишь
                                                     # распарсить его нужным образом
        from_ = parseaddr(mail_.get('From'))[1]      # здесь адрес автора письма

imap_session.close()                                 # не забывайте закрывать сессию
imap_session.logout()
```